# How to test graphics cards without a compatible PSU?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-quadro

I've recently been given five Nvidia Quadro 4000 graphics cards.

However, I am uncertain wether they are in proper working condition. 3 are labeled as "defect", but I suspect this could be an easy to fix issue.

I've considered simply plugging them in my own PC, but my PSU's cables are not compatible with the connectors on the cards.

**How would it be possible to test these cards?**

I've considered going to a computer shop and paying them a fee, but since there is a possibility all 5 cards might be dead, I'd rather not put too much money towards doing so.

Comment: Get a PSU with the right connectors?

Comment: I'd very much like to avoid buying an PSU incompatible with my current hardware to test cards that may or may not be broken.

Comment: If you don't have a compatible PSU, then you have no way to power them for proper testing, so I'm not sure what you're expecting from us..?  What kind of PSU do you have? What kind of connectors do you need for the card? Why do you think a newer PSU with those connectors would be incompatible with your existing hardware?

Comment: How you going to properly test without mounting to a motherboard and installing some OS?

Comment: The connectors on my R9 390 and the ones on the quadro simply are not the same, that's why they aren't compatible: I physically cannot plug them in.

Comment: To be fair, I'm not necessarily expecting a hardware solution, just what would be the best way to get them tested, whether that be paying someone, buying an adaptor or something else entirely.

Comment: Tell us what connectors your PSU or current card has and what connectors your "defective" cards have. Without knowing what you have we cannot say what won't work. For some things you can get adaptors and some things you can't.

Comment: For example 1:https://www.google.com/search?q=sata+power+to+molex&gws_rd=ssl 2:https://www.google.com/search?q=6+pin+pcie+to+molex we can't know what to suggest if you won't tell us why what you have doesn't fit. Telling us it "just doesn't fit" is doing yourself a disservice.

Comment: Please provide a photo of the card’s connectors.

Comment: I would, but I dont have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: How to test if my  computer works with no power source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see where you're coming from - why spend good money just to see if something works.

Unfortunately, the only way to test if your graphics cards work (and, not only that, but if they work *reliably* under stress and over time) is to install them into a properly configured, compatible PC. That includes using a compatible and compliant power supply.

If you don't envisage doing this often, might be best to see your local computer repair / system builder specialist.

As for this:

> 3 are labeled as "defect", but I suspect this could be an easy to fix issue.

Unless it's the GPU fan that's at fault, chances are you *won't* be able to easily fix a defective card. The components are just too integrated these days. But you make good point in your comment, just because someone labelled something 'defective' doesn't mean it actually is.

Comment: I think it could be easy simply because I got the cards from a big company where the unofficial policy is to simply buy new stuff when problems appear rather than troubleshooting.

Comment: @AerisFang Ahh I see, good point, I'll edit my answer to reflect that.